# how can i change a date to a valid number or character?

Tags: r, date, character, converters

I have a date 2008-01-01 and its class in R is Date. 
When I try to save these dates in a table that has other values it change the format of date to a number like 13879! In addition, I cannot have 20080101!
I try to change the class of date to character but it gave me 2008-01-01 and made the class of my table to character!
Is there any way to change 2008-01-01 to 20080101 as a number?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [@GSee](http://stackoverflow.com/users/967840/gsee)'s answer is what you need, but you really should consider posting a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format` to covert it to a character string "20080101", then convert that to an `integer` (or `numeric`)

```
myDate <- as.Date("2008-01-01")
as.integer(format(myDate, "%Y%m%d"))
```